# Android Studio Emulator causes BSOD

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, android-studio, emulator

I am having an issue where my android studio emulator will cause BSOD randomly (every time with the error WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR). I have an open microsoft forums issue [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/bsod-wheauncorrectableerror-after-using-android/1b016650-9569-4a59-a17b-92f057638570) as well with more issue details.

[Here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqlyPwdX4LpxjEm-DJgvR2JgTtll?e=Dip3gJ) are the 3 memory dumps as examples.

I have updated my drivers using Windows updater + Intel upgrade assistant. I am using a Gigabyte G5 MD.

Comment: I read the Microsoft post. Make sure ALL your drivers:  Motherboard (=BIOS), Video and Network as a minimum. Be very careful updating BIOS.

Comment: So I am doing this from memory so don't blame me if memory doesn't serve correctly.  I did Android development for quite some time and a dirty little secret was that the emulator that Visual Studio provided was better than the one using Android Studio.  Android has a qemu based one and VS uses some Microsoft proprietary thingamajig if I remember.  Android Studio can use Microsoft's emulator and visa-versa.  It's been a while but I believe that I am still correct.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Very cool! I'll def give this a shot. Quick question.... if I use a VS emulator, will I still get all the tools (logcat, resource monitor, DB modifier, etc) associated? Can I still get it to work with android studio's one click builds, debugging mode, etc?

Comment: I believe so.. but the 80s were good to me so I don't completely remember.